# Is a newly added Google Places place available to all my apps using the same account?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

If I add a new place via https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/add-place can I only request that place before moderation with that server-key?

Or would this place also be available to my other apps with Google Places (iOS, Android, JS) that are on the same Google-account, but with different keys?

Answer (score 0):

Your new places should be available in all your apps which access the API using any of the API keys under the same project in google developers console.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I couldn't find this in the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Just based on experience. And based on the fact that a project usually share the same resources